# How to target anchors in a div in the same page

Tags: html, css

I'm struggling with some anchors / other html pages ( buttons on left) to be displayed in another div in the same page ( to be more exactly in the right ). Are there any solutions to this with div? Or maybe with frame/iframe, even jQuery any tips please?

[image: In the image you've got the source code]

Comment: you need to explain your problem a little better, what are you exactly trying to achieve ?

Comment: I've got 2 divs: One on the left that holds some of my pages( Buttons)and the second one is on the right side of the page and what i'm trying is to open the pages on the left with a click and the result to be showed on the right div

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Are there any solutions to this with div?

1. Fetch the content with JavaScript (e.g. XMLHttpRequest).
2. Strip out the bits you don't need (e.g. everything except the contents of the `<body>`
3. Use DOM manipulation to add it to the div

> Or maybe with frame/iframe

That is exactly what iframes were designed for. Set the `target` attribute of the anchor to the `name` of the iframe

---

Loading content into a portion of a page comes with a lot of gotchas. At the very least it interferes with the ability of visitors to link to the content they are actually viewing (although you can use the History API and `pushState` to compensate for that). It is almost always a better idea to just link to a new page which includes (via a template) any content that is common to all the pages.

Comment: thanks for replying and I'd pretty much appreciate if you could show me exactly how to use iframe and obtain what i want cause I'm not really a pro in html. I don't have enough knowledge, thanks in advance

Comment: What have you tried so far? Have you written any code? Have you looked at any documentation? You shouldn't need a custom written example to get started, iframes are not complicated.

Comment: as you can see from the picture I've tried it with div, I couldn't implement what I wanted to do with that div with iframe instead. And yes I've seen plenty documentation about iframes and can't figure out how to exactly put my webpages to be displayed on the right on the same page with iframe

Comment: I can't see anything from the picture. I can't make out 3pt text. Look at [the spec for iframe](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/present/frames.html#h-16.5). Try to use it. Ask a question after you've had a go.

Comment: Right click on it and view image, or save it to desktop should do the trick

Answer (score 0):

If the page links to a HTML page you can append an `iframe` using jQuery as follows:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.button').click(function(){
    // Prevent Default Action
    event.preventDefault();
    // get the href parameter
    var url = $(this).attr('href');
    // Append the iframe
    $('#content').append('<iframe src="'+ url +'"></iframe>');
  });
});
```

#### [Here is a working Example](http://jsfiddle.net/Eaz92/2/)

If you are able to return a `JSON` or `XML` response you can use `$.ajax` to get the response and then append it inside a `div` instead of an `iframe`.